# Uninstalling with Install4j pops up a message saying "Preparing to Install." Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: uninstallation, install4j

When uninstalling using an installer created with Install4j.exe a message pops up saying "Preparing to Install" instead of "Preparing to Uninstall" This is confusing to customers. Is there a way to fix this? I verified this with an installer that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer the case since install4j 6.1, the text is now "Preparing to uninstall" for the uninstaller.